# Docusign embedded signing ceremony step by step guide

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

Is there a step-by-step guide for using Docusign embedded signing ceremony? For example, how to create a secret key, create a user for the signer, etc...

I watched the 'deep-dive' video but I find myself not sure of some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, there is including the code in GitHub.

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/quickstart-request-signature-embedded

https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant

The code you are looking is the very first example:

https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant/blob/master/lib/examples/eg001EmbeddedSigning.js

Comment: Hi. Sorry for such a late reply. I was looking over my previous questions and just realized that I forgot about this... Thanks